# How to fix error when running cucumber tutorial on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

I am trying to run a [cucumber tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_annotations.htm) example on a mac. I followed the instructions of the tutorial to that given page (as far as I understood the instructions), and created the files as explained on that page (i.e. files `annotation.java`, `runTest.java` and `outline.feature`) as explained in the package `Annotation` under `src/test/java`.

Used versions:

- MacOS 10.13.6
- eclipse: 2019-03 (?) (unable to find eclipse version, really annoying!)
- junit 4.10
- gherkin 2.9.3

The files are saved and do not show any obvious error in the `eclipse` editor. But when I do `runTest.java`-> `runAs` -> `JUnit test`I get the following error:

```
Feature: annotation

  #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
  Background:  [90m# Annotation/outline.feature:4[0m
     User navigates to Facebook Given 
     I am on Facebook login page


  #Scenario with AND
  Scenario:                         [90m# Annotation/outline.feature:9[0m
    [90mWhen [0m[90mI enter username as "[0m[90m[1mTOM[0m[90m"[0m  [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.runtime.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter (file:/Users/adietz/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-core/1.0.2/cucumber-core-1.0.2.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.runtime.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[1A    [31mWhen [0m[31mI enter username as "[0m[31m[1mTOM[0m[31m"[0m  [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
      [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
        at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)
        at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation/outline.feature:10)
      [0m
    [90mAnd [0m[90mI enter password as "[0m[90m[1mJERRY[0m[90m"[0m [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
[1A    [36mAnd [0m[36mI enter password as "[0m[36m[1mJERRY[0m[36m"[0m [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
    [90mThen [0m[90mLogin should fail[0m          [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
[1A    [36mThen [0m[36mLogin should fail[0m          [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m

  #This is how background can be used to eliminate duplicate steps
  Background:  [90m# Annotation/outline.feature:4[0m
     User navigates to Facebook Given 
     I am on Facebook login page


  #Scenario with BUT
  Scenario:                                [90m# Annotation/outline.feature:15[0m
    [90mWhen [0m[90mI enter username as "[0m[90m[1mTOM[0m[90m"[0m         [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
[1A    [31mWhen [0m[31mI enter username as "[0m[31m[1mTOM[0m[31m"[0m         [90m# annotation.enterUsername(String)[0m
      [31mjava.lang.NullPointerException
        at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)
        at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation/outline.feature:16)
      [0m
    [90mAnd [0m[90mI enter password as "[0m[90m[1mJERRY[0m[90m"[0m        [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
[1A    [36mAnd [0m[36mI enter password as "[0m[36m[1mJERRY[0m[36m"[0m        [90m# annotation.enterPassword(String)[0m
    [90mThen [0m[90mLogin should fail[0m                 [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
[1A    [36mThen [0m[36mLogin should fail[0m                 [90m# annotation.checkFail()[0m
    [90mBut [0m[90mRelogin option should be available[0m [90m# annotation.checkRelogin()[0m
[1A    [36mBut [0m[36mRelogin option should be available[0m [90m# annotation.checkRelogin()[0m

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)
    at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation/outline.feature:10)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Annotation.annotation.enterUsername(annotation.java:22)
    at ✽.When I enter username as "TOM"(Annotation/outline.feature:16)
```

I am not an expert in `java`, and certainly no expert with `eclipse`. So how do I fix the error? And how can I get in contact with the creators of that tutorial so they can update the tutorial (make it more clear)?

Comment: This is an ancient cucumber version. Latest ones have more goodies. Use the one at this - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8. Guessing u are using Java 9. Downgrade to java 8 to remove access warnings. You are better off following the official docs - https://cucumber.io/docs

Comment: Is the browser opening with the site mentioned? The method of using firefox driver is also pretty old.

Comment: So maybe you can recommend a more up-to-date tutorial?

Comment: Have not come across one which deals with the latest versions. U could try ur luck with the official docs.